# jquery.getJSON() error handling

Tags: jquery, json, error-handling

I am using [jquery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), but I don't know how to do error handling. And these are some situations that I need to handle.

1) what if the returned data  is null?

2) what if the returned data is not json parseable?

3) what if some error message is returned? For example, the server returned `HTTP ERROR`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `$.getJSON()` returns a promise object uou can use the `.fail()` promise callback for case 2 and 3... case 1 needs to be handled in the success callback itself

```
jQuery.getJSON(...).fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){
    if(status == 'parseerror'){
        //not valid json
    } else {
        //some other error
    }
})
```

Comment: i don't get `status == 'parseerror'`, if the returned data is not parseable, the status will be `parseerror`?

Comment: @Cacheing yes look at the [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation for `error` callback

Comment: thanks, but it should be handled this way even if the server returned some error by setting `response.setStatus`?

Comment: @Cacheing yes... then the status will be `error` and you can use `jqXHR.status` to get the response status like 400/404/403/500 etc... also you can read the response content using `jqXHR.responseText`